# jquery, how to set active item for tabbed navigation

Tags: jquery

I have following code, that display tabbed info on each nav. item click:

```
$('#unlock_nav a').click(function() {
    $('.navActive').hide().removeClass('navActive'); 

    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).show().addClass('navActive');

    return false;       
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id="unlock_nav">
  <ul> 
    <li id="i1"><a href="#tunic" class="unlock_ni" style="width:53px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:0;left:30px;z-index:3;background-image: url(http://www.mysiteurl/buttn_tunic_white.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; cursor:pointer;"></a>
    </li>        
    <li id="i2"><a href="#jacket"  class="unlock_ni" style="width:67px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:22px;left:30px;z-index:3;background-image: url(http://www. http://www.mysiteurl/buttn_jacket_white.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; cursor:pointer;"></a>
    </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we would have to see the HTML. I don't really see why you can't simply do `$(this).addClass('active');` in the click function, however.

Comment: i can not simply set active, adding css class. Please see following;$("#unlock_nav a").hover(function () {
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.mysiteurl/images/buttn_' + $(this).attr('href').slice(1) +'_pink.png)');

 },

 function(){
 $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://www. http://www.mysiteurl/images//buttn_' +  $(this).attr('href').slice(1) + '_white.png)');
 });

Comment: Some HTML:<div id="unlock_nav">
<ul> 
<li id="i1"><a href="#tunic"   class="unlock_ni" style="width:53px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:0;left:30px;z-index:3;background-image: url(http://www.mysiteurl/buttn_tunic_white.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; cursor:pointer;"></a>
  </li>        
<li id="i2"><a href="#jacket"  class="unlock_ni" style="width:67px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:22px;left:30px;z-index:3;background-image: url(http://www. http://www.mysiteurl/buttn_jacket_white.png);background-repeat:no-repeat; cursor:pointer;"></a>
  </li>  
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Please put that code into your question, it is illegible in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight the clicked link with a `navActive` class, you can just use  `this` keyword.  However, calling `.hide()` might not be the behaviour you want.

```
$('#unlock_nav a').click(function() {
    $('.navActive').removeClass('navActive'); 
    $(this).addClass('navActive');
    return false; // (optional) prevents #anchor appearing in URL bar       
});
```

**Try out a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/u9e3X/8/.**

Comment: Thanks, but I need to highlight <a > element or <li> not the content.

Comment: so when you click an <a> element, you want it to be given the `navActive` class (and any other `navActive`'s to be cleared.  Does my edit help at all?